# FrameLayout borders in Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

What I have to implement in order to limit the max size of a FrameLayout or the View inside it?

I am using a FrameLayout for my Android app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dog_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have added a View to it:

```
    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.dog_holder);
    dog = new DogView(this);
    frame.addView(dog);
```

(DogView extends View)

I am initializing the View with a bitmap:

```
my_dog = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dog);
```

I want to move around the picture (I have implemented the touch controls) but not to be able to move outside it. Good example is a picture gallery app: while a picture is zoomed you can go around it but on the borders there is bouncy effect which doesn't allow to go into the dark side.

**What I have to implement to stop me when I try to go outside the dimension of the bitmap?**